# Is there a JSON stringify and parse capability for VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, json, file-format

I looked on the [JSON.org website](http://json.org/) but I couldn't find any JSON library for Visual Basic .NET, does one exist? Did anyone have any success using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) with VB.NET?

Comment: There's also [Jayrock](http://jayrock.berlios.de/).

Answer (score 8):

Have you seen the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class?

Comment: Wow. That's inbuilt functionality! but it appears to be only Net Framework 3.5 compatible.. I typically target 2.0.

Comment: It's available in .NET 2.0 by adding a reference to System.Web.Extensions assembly and then using System.Web.Script.Serialization namespace.

Comment: Too much good stuff in 3.5 to stay with 2.0.  You're seriously missing out on some stuff that will make your life much easier, such as LINQ, anonymous types, better AJAX, better AD support, ...

Comment: Installing ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions 1.0 will install the System.Web.Extensions assembly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) to serialize/deserialize JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I use [csjson](http://sourceforge.net/projects/csjson/) and it works pretty well.

Though we're not sure if its fully functional since the samples say its "pre-release".