# How do I show a YouTuber's subscriber count in Visual Basic 2012?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, youtube-api

I want to have a form that shows a youtuber's subscriber count. I already installed the API and I got this code:

```
Imports Google.GData.YouTube
Imports Google.GData.Client
Imports Google.GData.Extensions

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim subshelper As New Service
        Dim feedUrl As String = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/SkyDoesMinecraft"
        Dim profile As ProfileEntry = subshelper.Get(feedUrl)
        Dim subscount As Integer = profile.Statistics.SubscriberCount

        Label1.Text = subscount
    End Sub
End Class
```

I got this error though:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException' occurred in Google.GData.Client.dll

Additional information: Execution of request failed:
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/SkyDoesMinecraft
```

Can anyone help me here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *only* thing you care about is using the YouTube Data API to get the subscriber count for that one channel, then your best bet is probably just to make a [generic HTTP request](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301102) (without using any of the GData libraries) for

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/SkyDoesMinecraft?v=2&alt=json
```

and then using a [JSON-parsing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259817/is-there-a-json-stringify-and-parse-capability-for-vb-net) to read the value of `yt$statistics` -> `subscriberCount`